# Delete link from a changeset from a code review in TFS 2013?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to delete the link between a code review and a changeset in TFS 2013?  We are on TFS 2013 Update 3 and are using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

A colleague checked in a code change but mistakenly typed in the wrong work item ID, thus associating his changeset with the wrong work item number.  We were able to link the correct work item (a bug in this case) to the changeset, but we can't seem to figure out how to remove the link from the code review, which is totally unrelated.  Unlike bugs, user stories, and other work item types, code reviews appear in the Team Explorer window, and the only options available are Open Work Item, New Linked Work Item, Create a Copy of Work Item, and Link to An Existing Item.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the code review request from the TFS web portal then you'll be able to remove the changeset link to it.

Comment: Thank you for realizing that I meant Code Review *Request*.